# JSON single value parsing

Tags: json, go

In python you can take a json object and grab a specific item from it without declaring a struct, saving to a struct then obtaining the value like in Go. Is there a package or easier way to store a specific value from json in Go?

python

```
res = res.json()
return res['results'][0]
```

Go

```
type Quotes struct {
AskPrice string `json:"ask_price"`
}

quote := new(Quotes)
errJson := json.Unmarshal(content, &quote)
if errJson != nil {
    return "nil", fmt.Errorf("cannot read json body: %v", errJson)
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can decode into a `map[string]interface{}` and then get the element by key.

```
func main() {
    b := []byte(`{"ask_price":"1.0"}`)
    data := make(map[string]interface{})
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &data)
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

    if price, ok := data["ask_price"].(string); ok {
        fmt.Println(price)
    } else {
        panic("wrong type")
    }
}
```

Structs are often preferred as they are more explicit about the type. You only have to declare the fields in the JSON you care about, and you don't need to type assert the values as you would with a map (encoding/json handles that implicitly).

Comment: This won't work if there are nested objects in the JSON

Answer (score 3):

Try either [fastjson](https://github.com/valyala/fastjson) or [jsonparser](https://github.com/buger/jsonparser). `jsonparser` is optimized for the case when a single JSON field must be selected, while `fastjson` is optimized for the case when multiple unrelated JSON fields must be selected.

Below is an example code for `fastjson`:

```
var p fastjson.Parser
v, err := p.Parse(content)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// obtain v["ask_price"] as float64
price := v.GetFloat64("ask_price")

// obtain v["results"][0] as generic JSON value
result0 := v.Get("results", "0")
```